# TFS2015.3 Git won't merge pull request

Tags: git, tfs, git-merge, tfs-2015, pull-request

We are using a TFS git repository, using branches and pull requests to manage updates to master on project A, and it works fine.

We created another repo for project B (main difference to A in that it contains quite a lot more data, including some binaries) and everything works OK **except TFS fails to merge even the simplest pull requests, e.g. a one line comment change:**

[image]

As the text suggests, we *are* able to merge locally then push back to master, but this defeats part of the purpose of the pull request process via TFS.

Any ideas?

Update, more info about repo size:
[image]

Update #2, more info about file contents (hex):

[image]

Comment: There is a merge conflict. Perhaps if you can handle the pull request through a web interface you could get a web interface asking you how to handle the conflict but Visual Studio can't do this, you will need to do it locally and handle the conflict there. This is basically a limitation of how TFS handles the pull request.

Comment: On the other hand, you really should avoid pull requests which cannot merge cleanly. The correct way to handle this would be to reject the pull request, let the developer who sent it do this fetch, merge cycle to make his pull request updated, then re-submit the request which should not merge cleanly on the server.

Comment: And the reason for that is that **I**, that is asked to look at and merge the pull request should not be required to handle merge conflicts. The original developer is the one best equipped with the knowledge of how to do this (usually, obviously there will be exceptions to this rule), and so you should send the pull request back to him and let him fix it before resubmitting.

Comment: I'd agree, except there is no conflict - this is an addition of 6 characters to one line in a text file (i.e. the simplest change we ever make, which works fine in our other repo). This is why it seems very strange, and why I think perhaps the size of the repo is relevant.

Comment: Are you sure the machine where this "local merge works fine" has done a pull recently on `master`?  Maybe the version of `master` they have locally merges fine but the `origin/master` version has changes that cause a merge conflict?

Comment: What encoding is the file? Does Git think it is binary, as an example?

Comment: @patricksteele Yes, it's only one user using it (both local and on TFS) right now so we are sure of no conflicting changes.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Interesting idea, how do I check that? TFS can certainly understand the change (first screenshot)

Comment: I tend to just use a hex editor, like [HxD](https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/). If the file contains "00" bytes every other byte, then Git will give up and think it is binary.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I've copied the file from Linux to Windows (using pscp) and opened using Hexinator (that I had already), and can confirm file does *not* contain "00" bytes every other byte. (see attached image).

Answer (score 0):

> As the text suggests, we are able to merge locally then push back to master, but this defeats part of the purpose of the pull request process via TFS.

No, not really. PR are not the place where to solve conflicts.

If you want to merge a PR, it should be mergeable, so you have to fix it locally (the way you want, by merge or rebase) and push it. The PR will be updated, TFS will check if it's mergeable and you will be able to do the merge.

Comment: Thanks, I quite agree, but there is no conflict - the code change is just a few characters addition to one file (the kind of change we do all the time in Project A). My comment about being able to do it locally was just to make it clear that there wasn't a merge conflict that we had to fix when doing it locally - it just merges fine.